# javascript - Delete and shift elements after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a list of panels with IDs in the form `npc_parent_i` (where i is its index), all of which have a class `npc-container`. They form a vertical line with `npc_parent_1` at the top. I would like to accomplish this animation:

While `npc_parent_1` fades out, all of the `npc_parent_i` beneath the first move towards the top of the page, eventually completely overlapping `npc_parent_1`. Once the animation is finished, I want to remove the element `npc_parent_1`.

Here is my current code:

```
var panelHeight = $('#npc_parent_1').outerHeight();
$.when(
    $('#npc_parent_1').fadeOut(750),
    $('.npc-container').animate({top:-panelHeight}, 750)
).then(
    function(){
        var npcPanel = document.getElementById('npc_parent_1');
        npcPanel.parentNode.removeChild(npcPanel);
        $('.npc-container').css('top', '0px');
    }
);
```

The animation runs correctly, but when the element gets deleted, the rest of the panels shift up, then back down as their top values are set back to 0. I think the issue may be that `npc_panel_1` also has the class `npc-container`, but it doesn't move during the animation.

How can I keep the panels in place while deleting the element above them?

Comment: Perhaps remove `$('.npc-container').css('top', '0px');` ?

Comment: Without that line, the panels will stay shifted upwards after the first one is deleted.

Comment: So you actually want them to go back to their original positions or not?

Comment: Perhaps you can setup a jsfiddle.net which might illustrate better.

Comment: After the first panel is overlapped,  the panel is deleted. When it is deleted, the rest of the panels are shifted upwards (by the height of the first panel) because they assume the position of the deleted panel while having non-zero `top` values. The line which resets the `top` value brings them back down to their positions after the animation and before the deletion. I don't know how to keep them in place while deleting the first element.

Comment: Please at least post your HTML so we can make a fiddle for you!

Comment: I had never made one before, sorry for the delay. I'm not sure why the animate function isn't working, but here is a start. http://jsfiddle.net/2VpU4/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `fadeOut` was causing you troubles.  Have a look at this code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.when(
    $('#test1').animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 750),
    $('.npc-container').not('#test1').animate({
        top: '-200px'
    }, 750)).then(

    function () {
        var npcPanel = document.getElementById('test1');
        npcPanel.parentNode.removeChild(npcPanel);
        $('.npc-container').css('top', '0px');
    });
});
```

I have also set the `position` of `.npc-container` to `relative`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/958e6/ notice also that jQuery UI is needed for `animate` to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just a question, does the not() work for any  element passed to it? And thanks for the tip on the jQuery UI.

Comment: There are 2 types we could have used here http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ which would be $('.npc-container:not(#test_1)') or http://api.jquery.com/not/ which is used above.  The first one works on a selection and the latter works on a collection of selections/jQuery objects that may have come about from another function such as a filter or such.  So to answer yes, you can exclude any element by selector with the first method and any jQuery object (which could well be an element selected by selector too) with the second

Answer (score 0):

fadeOut will set the opacity then sets the element to display: none. Which removes it from the layout flow. Animating the opacity property is a better bet.